# Replacing " " with comma (,) in SSIS

Tags: ssis, double, quotes, derived

I am trying to import a text file in which tab delimited and text qualifier is double quotes.
I am following guide:
http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2008/11/12/handling-embedded-text-qualifiers/

I want following text

```
"655295" "Keisuke" "" "Ueda" "1-2-2, Central Park East F201" "Utase, Mihama-Ku"
```

to convert to

```
"655295","Keisuke","","Ueda","1-2-2, Central Park East F201","Utase, Mihama-Ku"
```

I tried derived column transformation, but it did not help. I tried script component, but that didn't work either. Can someone please help me out here.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code in Script component:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        /*
         * Add your code here
         */
        String inputString = Row.line.ToString();

        int count = Row.line.Split('"').Length - 1;
        int counter = 1;

        while (counter < count)
        {
            if (counter % 2 == 0)
            {
                int StartIndex = GetNthIndex(inputString.ToString(), Convert.ToChar("\""), counter);
                int EndIndex = GetNthIndex(inputString.ToString(), Convert.ToChar("\""), counter + 1);

                inputString = inputString.ToString().Substring(0, StartIndex + 1) + "," +
                inputString.ToString().Substring(EndIndex);

            }
            else
            {
            }
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
        Row.OutputLine = inputString;
    }
    int GetNthIndex(string s, char t, int n)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            if (s[i] == t)
            {
                count++;
                if (count == n)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

take a variable and store the string in variable.

then using derieved column use string function as

```
REPLACE(@user:Variable1,"\" \"","\",\"")
```

This will work for your question...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by following steps:-

1) In flat file connection manager, please do the following things to configure it to get only one column per row -
 i. Don't put any **"Text qualifier"**
 ii. Row delimter  =  **{CR}{LF}**
 iii. Modifey Column delimited = {CR} and refresh the metadeta, so that you will see only one column. Please give it a specific name, I will mention it as "Col" as for now.

2) Add derived column transformation and put the expression as 
**"(DT_STR,100,1252)REPLACE(Col,"\" \"","\",\"")"**. You will get the below required output in the new column -

```
"655295","Keisuke","","Ueda","1-2-2, Central Park East F201","Utase, Mihama-Ku"
```

You can put this output in different flat-file and import that file into table using different DFT or package OR you can add script component to split it into different columns, so that you can import data into table using same DFT.